Is there any way to generate Slack App Configuration Token Programmatically
I have slack app and there are numerous instance from where my slack app will be connected for posting message.
So instead of generating manually token of app configuration token, How to generate it programmatically?
I did r&d but not found anything
Links I have searched:

https://github.com/slackapi/node-slack-sdk/issues/1622
https://api.slack.com/reference/manifests#config-tokens
Programmatically Get App-Level Token for Slack App with Socketmode Enabled

